# Keyframes not working in Safari and Chrome

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get my css slider to work on Safari and Chrome please?

It works fine in Firefox and Opera - haven't tested in IE yet.

Many thanks for any help

Lauren

```
@keyframes slidy {
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}



figure { position: absolute; width: 500%;
margin: 0; top: 0; left: 0;
animation: 20s slidy ease-in-out infinite; }
```

Comment: Could you please make a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it's not really that iOS doesn't support animations, it was a bug from WebKit. They [solved it in January](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/) and because of Chrome's fast updates it works in Chrome now, but not so on Safari, neither mobile nor desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

To make @Keyframes animations work on webkit-based browsers, you have to put the vendor specific prefixes, in this case `@-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation`.

You should always specify all of them: `-moz`, `-webkit`, `-o`, and the straight one, in a specific cascade order.

Read more on [Keyframe Animation Syntax](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).